# How to reset the animation after a gameobject is deactivated in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

I have a simple cube gameobject which has an animator component attached to it. This animator only controls one simple animation clip, this animation clip simply changes the scale of the gameobject from (1,1,1) to (2,2,2) in half a second.

Now in an another script lets say GameManager I trigger this animation by `anim.SetTrigger("Scaleup")` and thats works fine where the cube gameobject scales to the correct values which is (2,2,2).

All i'm after here is: When this cube gets deactivated and then reactivated again the animator does reset to its default state (Idle state) but the **size never gets back to its original scale which is (1,1,1) and stays at (2,2,2) no matter what I do** which it seems impossible in unity.

**How can I reset the values of the animation clip when a gameobject gets deactivated and reactivated again?**

I tried doing this `anim.enabled = false` and `anim.enabled = true` but it doesn't work. Help Guys.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with [tag:unityscript]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animator does not change any parameter which is not changed in the animation. In your example, the scale was changed by Scaleup animation and is never mentioned anywhere else.

Add a new simple animation to Idle state, add game object scale to it and make it constant (1.0, 1.0, 1.0). That will effectively reset your object's scale.